# Infinite loop when triggering redirect from componentDidUpdate using ReactTransitionsGroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router

I have recently implemented ReactTransitionsGroup to animate all my page transitions using react router (Velocty component is just a wrapper of ReactTransitionsGroup, so in practice is the same):

```
render () {
        return (
            <div className="app-layout">
                <NavBar location={this.props.location} />
                <VelocityTransitionGroup enter={{ animation: 'pageTransitionIn' }} leave={{ animation: 'pageTransitionOut' }}>
                    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                        key: this.props.location.pathname,
                    })}
                </VelocityTransitionGroup>
                <TimeOutModal />
                <Notifications />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

In my signup form, I have a a form component that once the signup request has successfully responded, the props will update and the component will trigger a redirect to the next signup step.

```
class SignUp extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate () {
        if (this.props.signup.success) {
            hashHistory.push('/confirm-signup')
        }
    }

    render() {//....//}

}
```

The problem is, once the redirect is triggered I enter in a infinite loop, since the ReactTransitionsGroup makes the component stay for a few miliseconds, triggering the redirect again.

I manage to "fix" it, using a setTimeout on the redirect, but I don't find this solution really elegant:

```
componentDidUpdate () {
        if (this.props.signup.success) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                hashHistory.push('/confirm-signup')
            }, 500)
        }
    }
```

Do you find any other solutions to this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would say to do the redirect in your form handler. Based on the fact that `signup.success` is a prop, I assume that you are using some sort of global store and you would have to rewrite a bunch of code to do that.

#### Edit

You could add a `hasTransitioned` property to your component, which you set when it transitions.

```
class Signup extends React.Component {
  hasTransitioned = false

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.signup.success && !this.hasTransitioned) {
      this.hasTransitioned = true
      hashHistory.push('/confirm-signup')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already tested this approach, but the infinite loop is triggered anyway. It seems that the path is not changed immediately after executing the push method and every time componentDidUpdate gets executed, the pathname is still '/signup'.

Comment: Does the transition group render the exiting component with the previous props? The re-matching is triggered by the`history` module when it receives the new location, so it shouldn't be using the old location unless that is the case. The best solution might just be to move where you are doing the navigation.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the transition updates the old component with the same props, so location.pathname keeps the same value. But in general, I would say that is pretty bad that every time time a component is unmounted it gets updated in parallel with the new mount of the new component.

Comment: It makes sense to maintain the old props for the exiting component, it is just an issue for you since your component has a side effect. I updated my answer with another possible solution.